# Allow broswer to download images from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a compute engine and google cloud storage work together.
The compute engine has a tomcat running allow browsers to load a page and get the images from the google cloud storage.

How could i allow the html page (generated by the servlet) to download several images from the google cloud storage where the images are not public shared??

What i expect is when the broswers downloaded the html page then it will request the images directly from the cloud storage, but how can i allow the broswer to do it without making the images public sharable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky but possible. If you want to manage some sort of authorization scheme for who can and cannot view GCS images, you'll need a service which can vend short-term, signed URLs to parties that your service decides are authorized. You then embed the URLs in the image tags of your dynamically-generated HTML pages, or you fetch the URLs from the server with JavaScript.

The gcloud-java library has a [signURL](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.2.7/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.html#signUrl(com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.SignUrlOption...)) method for generating such a URL.

Another option would be to simply obfuscate the image URLs to something unguessable and rotate them every so often.

Comment: URL url = storage.signUrl(
               BlobInfo.builder("bucket", "img.jpg").build(),
               10, 
               TimeUnit.SECONDS,
               SignUrlOption.signWith(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(keyPath)))
               );
       
             String imgPath = url.toString();
             //out.write("Img path=" + imgPath + "<br>");             
       out.write("<img width=360 height=240 src=\"" + imgPath + "\"><br>");